# Get details of current media file playing in android media player

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

Is there any way to get the details of media files that is executed in android(default) media player?

Answer (score 2):

This thread might help you to find what you are looking for: http://www.alexc.me/android-music-app-service-currently-playing-song/231/

Regards

Comment: When posting links please copy paste the relevant part of the answer. This link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can start playing a media file on your phone with the debug bridge enabled (or just use the emulator) and check with LogCat if there is an Intent - but as far as I know the SDK does not provide a way to retrieve details for played media files