# Android How do I get a reference to a current instance of media player?

Tags: android

I want to create an application that runs everytime a song is played, say, a notification saying the title of the song and the corresponding artist. A similar application exists - Lyrics App. It gets the lyrics of the song currently played. So, this means, what I wanted to happen is possible.

The question is, How? How do I access the current instance of media player.. I need to do this to integrate my listeners to it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Get details of currect media file playing in android media player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606846/get-details-of-currect-media-file-playing-in-android-media-player)

Comment: Geez! Thanks a lot! I was trying broadcast receivers but then I gave up as I couldn't make it work. So I tried other ways like getting the instance of the MediaPlayer. This helped me a lot!!! :)